# Start second Activity with ImageView animation like Play Store

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-animation, android-imageview

I'm developing a shop app and it simply goes to the details of the selected item like regular stores.

I have a `GridView` in the first `Activity` which contains pictures and titles of items, then i start the second `Activity` when an item is selected and i show its details.

What i want is to make the picture which is in the `ImageView` of the first `Activity` move to place where it is going to be in the second `Activity`. like in Google Play Store.

And after that i wanna know how the picture is passed to the second `Activity`,
now i pass the download URL and use Glide to show it in the second `Activity` but in this way, somehow the image is passed...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: implement custom animation.

Comment: can u give me more details? @Vishal Patoliya ツ

Comment: What you're describing is called a Shared Element Transition. There's lots of tutorials out there once you know the right search term to use; this one, for example: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition

Comment: @LewisMcGeary that was exactly what i was looking for, thanks a lot